# C# - get content from URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, selenium-webdriver, asp.net-web-api

How can I get the content from URL With linkedin Website, When i give URL with EmailID i need to get HTML Code as shown below. 
But, When i tried to access the URL using code, i am getting signin to linkedin issue.
I tried with this C# Code, But i am getting signin issue

```
string Url = "https://www.example.com/sales/gmail/profile/viewByEmail/" + 
        TextBox1.Text;//example@gmail.com
        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(Url);
        HtmlNode[] nodes=doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div").ToArray();
```

Can anyone please help me how can i get the html code with signin,
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The error couldn't really be any more descriptive, you're not signed in, what else can it do?

Comment: You should go through the [official developer docs for the LinkedIn API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/)

Comment: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/rest-api gives you some information

Comment: @ColinM
Is there anyway i can signin with developing the code and access the URL?

Comment: @Darnold I am new to rest-api, Can you please provide me a code or something that can achieve??

Answer (score 3):

The error tells you the exact cause of your problem - you need to sign in. There's 2 solutions here:

1. Just hook up a button to the login page. This is the hacky solution, I do not recommend it in any way. With that said, this is consistent with your current code.
2. Use the API, instead of using Selenium. I'm not sure why you need Selenium here: it appears you just want the data from LinkedIn. If that's what you're looking for, you need to use the [LinkedIn API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/). That's the correct way to pull information from LinkedIn if you plan to process it yourself.

I don't know your requirements, and maybe you *do* need the website in a browser. But to me, it looks like you need their API. Read up on some tutorials for it, and it will likely be able to preform your task far better than attempting to process the website in Selenium.

Comment: Can you please tell me how can i perform the first point

1.Just hook up a button to the login page. This is the hacky solution, I do not recommend it in any way. With that said, this is consistent with your current code.

Comment: @MohanKrishna You just need to webbrowser.open the login page, and then reuse the webbrowser that you opened to go to the value of url. This is going to look and feel terrible, but it's what you have to do.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if you want to manipulate a login form, you need a browser. You can try a headless browser like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org) or CasperJs. There are heaps of documentations and examples you can try before customize to your linkedin page. The headless browser works like a normal browser and enable you to write code to automate it.